# Crankset for single-speed vs racing bicycle

Tags: road-bike, single-speed

What is the difference between a crankset for singlespeed bikes and one for racing bikes?
If we assume that the teeth count is the same, would the SRAM S-Series be better than the SRAM Rival 1? Unfortunately I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

If it's not the same then something like the Rival 1 would be more flexible for possible future conversions to gravel/racing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chainline for a crankset intended for a singlespeed bike (track bike) will have its chainring centered (in the inboard/outboard sense) to align with the rear cog exactly. There are also similar cranksets that are intended for 1x systems. Do not confuse this with singlespeed though, 1x refers to the front chainring (singular) only.

A 'racing' crankset, as in a standard 2x road crankset will have mounts for two chainrings, each offset from this centre position (small ring inboard, large ring outboard).

I don't know what you're intending to do, but if you're hoping to have a bike that can 'do it all' with less fuss then I'd get a 2x and commit to a front derailleur.

Personally, I'm loving 1x myself for both road and gravel, I have a GRX 1x crankset, and a SRAM Force TT 1x crankset and am using narrow/wide chainrings on both.